# Where can I find documentation for Azure Functions using .NET 8?

Tags: azure-functions

[All of the examples I can find have Run as a static method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=python-v2%2Cisolated-process%2Cnodejs-v4&pivots=programming-language-csharp). But Visual Studio when creating the template for version 8 has them as an instantiated method:

```
public API(ILogger<API> logger)
{
    _logger = logger;
}

[Function("RunNow")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequest req)
{

    if (_logger.IsEnabled(LogLevel.Trace))
        _logger.LogTrace("RunNow called");

    return new OkObjectResult("Welcome to Azure Functions!");
}
```

Where can I find documentation for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here You should find some answers.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide?tabs=windows